Android-Manifest Activity tag- Screen orientation deprecated
Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Canary 5
The screen orientation tag in the manifest is deprecated, so I'm seeking an alternative solution.
Gradle plugin version - 8.3.1
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
suppress tool - tools:ignore="DiscouragedApi" 

Thanks!

What does hovering over the warning tell you? "I'm seeking an alternative solution." - what is the problem that you were solving with this attribute that you need a new solution for?

It provide the suppress tool suggestion - tools:ignore="DiscouragedApi"
After adding the suppress tool, it disappears warning, but I am looking for an alternative solution. @dominicoder


The tool suggestion would be quick fix action. I'm asking what extra information about the warning / deprecation does it tell you when you hover over it with your mouse. 2) Yes, I get you're looking for an alternative solution. But an alternative solution - for what? Again, what were you solving by using this discouraged API?


Inspection info: Discouraged APIs are allowed and are not deprecated, but they may be unfit for common use (e.g. due to slow performance or subtle behavior).

How did you fix it? @Mudra

No solution was found. @IshikaSingh

I'm getting this warning too:
"Should not restrict activity to fixed orientation. This may not be suitable for different form factors, causing the app to be letterboxed.
Inspection info: Discouraged APIs are allowed and are not deprecated, but they may be unfit for common use (e.g. due to slow performance or subtle behavior)."

Try     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); in your GetStartedActivity

Add this:
tools:ignore="DiscouragedApi, LockedOrientationActivity"
That should solve the warning.
